# Reading a tabulation of data with brackets and commas: OpenRead

Tags: import, files-and-directories, memory, editing

While I can read a data file containing the one/multiple line(s) of

```
1.314 -4.32 6.44 342.3
```

using

```
teststr = OpenRead["test_formatted.dat"];
Read[teststr, Table[Number, 4]]
```

I'm having difficulty reading a file which is formatted as

```
(1.314,0) (-4.32,1) (6.44,2) (342.3,3)
```

using any modification of above commands.

I want to avoid either (i) making new copies of original files and then format them externally using vim/sed [which can be done] because there are too many such huge files and I will run into memory constraints, or (ii) modifying the original files themselves to look like the first.

Can it be done with minimal changes to my above 2 lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

The following is not very nice, but works:

```
data = Import["file.txt", "Table"];
ToExpression@StringReplace[#, {"(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}] & /@ First@data
```

The idea is to convert the string to an expression; for that I first changed the parentheses to braces using `StringReplace`.

Might need a bit of fiddling if you use it for other file structures than the one you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most efficient approach is to specify explicit sequence of object types to read:

```
file = "(-1.314,0) (4.32,1) (6.44,2) (342.3,3)
(-1.314,0) (4.32,1) (6.44,2) (342.3,3)";
stream = StringToStream[file];
ReadList[stream, Flatten@Table[{Character, Number, Character, Number, Character, Character}, 4]]
```

> ```
> {{"(", -1.314`, ",", 0, ")", " ", "(", 4.32`, ",", 1, ")", " ", "(", 6.44`, ",", 2, ")", 
>   " ", "(", 342.3`, ",", 3, ")", "\n"},
>  {"(", -1.314`, ",", 0, ")", " ", "(", 4.32`, ",", 1, ")", " ", "(", 6.44`, ",", 2, ")", 
>   " ", "(", 342.3`, ",", 3, ")", EndOfFile}}
> ```

Note however that the above solution assumes that line separators in your file are `\n` (Unix-style), not `\r\n` (Windows-style). In the latter case the above solution should be modified as follows:

```
ReadList[stream, Flatten[
  Table[{Character, Number, Character, Number, Character, Character}, 4]~Join~{Character}]]
```

---

Another approach is to parse the file using string expressions:

```
Partition[StringCases[file, n : NumberString :> ToExpression[n]], 8]
```

> ```
> {{-1.314, 0, 4.32, 1, 6.44, 2, 342.3, 3}, 
>  {-1.314, 0, 4.32, 1, 6.44, 2, 342.3, 3}}
> ```

This solution will be slower than the `ReadList`-based method.

A bit faster (but dangerous) is to use undocumented `` Internal`StringToDouble `` instead of `ToExpression`:

```
Partition[StringCases[file, n : NumberString :> Internal`StringToDouble[n]], 8]
```

> ```
> {{-1.314, 0., 4.32, 1., 6.44, 2., 342.3, 3.}, 
>  {-1.314, 0., 4.32, 1., 6.44, 2., 342.3, 3.}}
> ```

If you run into memory constraints with this solution, you can process the file line-by-line:

```
file = "(-1.314,0) (4.32,1) (6.44,2) (342.3,3)
(-1.314,0) (4.32,1) (6.44,2) (342.3,3)";
stream = StringToStream[file];
Reap[While[(rec = Read[stream, Record]) =!= EndOfFile,
   Sow@StringCases[rec, n : NumberString :> Internal`StringToDouble[n]]]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{-1.314, 0., 4.32, 1., 6.44, 2., 342.3, 3.}, 
>  {-1.314, 0., 4.32, 1., 6.44, 2., 342.3, 3.}}
> ```

---

Don't forget to close the stream after importing the data:

```
Close[stream];
```